# Does .NET really use NFA for regular expression engine?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, algorithm

Article [Details of Regular Expression Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN says, that .NET devs decide to use for regular expressions traditional **NFA** engine, because it is faster than **POSIX NFA**, but it is not clear to me, why does this pattern works exponentially slow then?

```
var regex = new Regex("(a|aa)*b");
var b = regex.IsMatch("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac");
```

**This simple pattern matching take more than 30 minute to execute**. But if .NET uses traditional NFA, it is possible to simulate it and find match in **O(M*N)** time in the worst case, where M is pattern length and N is text length, which surely is not true in this case.

Article also explains that backtracking is the reason of slow execution, but I still have some questions that can't find answers

1. What is backtracking? is it only using already matched pattern again like this `(a|b)c/1`?
2. Does traditional **NFA** support backtracking, if no what modification does it need?
3. If NFA supports it, but need more slower algorithm to simulate, why .NET can't check if backtracking exist in the pattern, and use one algorithm and use another if it doesn't?

Comment: You should focus on one question at a time. I can easily explain to you what backtracking is in this context, but I don't have the answers to the other two questions, which means that I will either have to post an incomplete answer, or as I will do now, not post at all.

Comment: Questions are very related Lasse V. Karlsen, that's why i decide to ask in one question, please explain backtracking in answer if possible

Comment: Another example of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Beware! This question is a denial of service attack! The regular expression is still executing on my pretty powerful desktop computer now 1 hour and 30 minutes later. ;^)

Comment: @MartinLiversage, I just stop after 20 mins, and decide to write more than 30 minutes :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile a regular expression to a NFA or a DFA, although the DFA calculated from an NFA may be impractically large. You can match a NFA with or without backtracking, although the schemes that work without back-tracking usually put more constraints on the regular expression language, and on which matches are found when there are many possible matches.

Your example is slow because the matcher has to decide very often whether to match with a or aa, and whether to try matching the final b. Backtracking works like running a recursive function which, at each step, makes recursive calls on itself for each possibility - recursively match with a and if that fails recursively match with aa and if that fails recursively match with b.

Microsoft seem to be saying that their sort of backtracking is faster than POSIX because POSIX backtracking will arrange for a recursive search that carries on until it is sure that it has found the longest possible match. The Microsoft version still backtracks, but it does not have extra checks that carry on until there is a guarantee that they have found the longest possible match. There is an example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Regular expression matchers without backtracking can work by accepting input one character at a time, and keeping track of which states in the NFA are live at that time - there may be many such states. It is hard to make this work with back-references, because then the state of the NFA cannot be described by just saying whether a state is live or not.

Comment: thanks @mcdowella, could you also give more explanation what is backtracking? is it using matched pattern again, as I ask in question under 1 point?

Comment: There is a general description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking. A rough idea is bool f(charsMatched, string) { foreach (possible match for charsMatched) {if (f(charsMatched + len matched here, string)) return true;} return false}. If you work this through on paper you will see that you move forward as you find matches and retreat - returning false in a recursive call - if you find matches. The retreats are the reason for the name backtracking.